# Can't connect kivy remote server to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, android-emulator, kivy

I installed kivy remote shell apk file on my android and it is showing:

```
ssh -p8000 admin@192.168.0.2
```

but when I type this command on the ubuntu terminal it gives me this error:

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.0.2 port 8000: Invalid key length
```

I read that something related to 2048 bits or 1024 bits is not being accepted in some key algorithm but really have no clue what that means. I tried generating a different key (don't know what key) but it results in the same error.

I can run the file using `buildozer` but then every time I need to transfer the `apk` file to my android, I need to install and check the functionality of the application.

My main motive is to test the app on android simultaneously while making the `kivy` application on `ubuntu` (just like to use the android phone as an emulator in android studio). I couldn't find any appropriate videos on this concept as well.